# Spring batch steps not executing in the order expected

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying the below job configuration for spring batch, but it doesn't seem to executing the steps in the order that I need. What am I doing wrong with the configuration?

Spring batch version : 4.3.6

- I want to skip step2 based on the decider. If it returns "PROCESS_EVENTS", then go to step2 else go to step3 directly and execute further steps.
- Below are 2 valid scenarios expected
- (a). Decider returns "PROCESS_EVENTS" then - step1 -> step2 -> step3 ->
  step4
- (b). Decider returns "NO_EVENTS" then step1 -> step3 -> step4

Instead of above, its executing - step1 -> step3 -> step2..

```
public Job dataFetchJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("dataFetchJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(step1())
            .next(decider())
                .on(PROCESS_EVENTS)
                .to(step2())
            .from(decider())
                .on(NO_EVENTS)
                .to(step3(fileReader(), fileProcessor(), fileWriter()))
            .next(step2())
            .next(step3(fileReader(), fileProcessor(), fileWriter()))
            .next(step4(indexReader(), indexProcessor(), indexWriter()))
            .end()
            .listener(dataListener())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted it out. We have to use "from" to start the flow from the branch. Below is the way I have configured the job now and it works as expected.

```
public Job dataFetchJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("dataFetchJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(step1())
            .next(decider())
                .on(PROCESS_EVENTS)
                .to(step2())
            .from(decider())
                .on(NO_EVENTS)
                .to(step3(fileReader(), fileProcessor(), fileWriter()))
            .from(step3(fileReader(), fileProcessor(), fileWriter()))
              .next(step4(indexReader(), indexProcessor(), indexWriter()))
            .from(step2())
              .next(step3(fileReader(), fileProcessor(), fileWriter()))
              .next(step4(indexReader(), indexProcessor(), indexWriter()))
            .end()
            .listener(dataListener())
            .build();
}
```